# Traceback: AttributeError: Symbol not Found

Tags: python, python-2.7

Running the one line script `import pysodium` crashes, and I can't figure out why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysodium import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysodium/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    sodium.crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix): symbol not found
```

What would be causing this? All wrappers are installed. All dependencies are installed. Error is a boatload of help.

I have done everything I can think of, and no resolution thus far.

NOTES:

- Libsodium; Installed via GitHub .ZIP; v1.0.7
- Libtool; Installed via Shell Script; v2.4.2
- PySodium; v6.8 Installed via pip install
- Google; No results
- Bing; Same as google, but more ads
- SO; No help
- Docs; LOL. What docs?
- Reinstalled; Done. No change.
- Python version: 2.7.11 downloaded via python.org

UPDATE: Just updated python to 2.7.11. Slightly altered message, but still no more help.

UPDATE 2: libsodium was corrupted to the point of looking encrypted. Go figure. I reinstalled [downloading from GitHub](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases) and using the instructions [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=5a088cc7506a8ca53c5820f040c1193f&p=1676317&postcount=5).

Thanks to all for all the help, and happy whatever doesn't offend you!

Comment: Can you specify the versions you are using of pysodium and libsodium and how you installed them?

Comment: I look s like a version mismatch, can you in addition to the versions use post the way you installed it?

Comment: @Markon Done the best I could. Still looking for more info of course.

Comment: @KlausD. Done the best I could. Still looking for more info of course.

Comment: What does "installed via github" mean? How exactly did you install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same issue on OSX.

```
>>> import pysodium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysodium/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    sodium.crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix): symbol not found

>>> import ctypes
>>> import ctypes.util
>>> 
>>> sodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('sodium') or ctypes.util.find_library('libsodium'))
>>> sodium
<CDLL 'None', handle fffffffffffffffe at 103e967d0>
>>> ctypes.util.find_library('libsodium')
>>> ctypes.util.find_library('sodium')
```

This implies it didn't find it.

After running `brew install libsodium` the command works, though. Now, either the library is not installed (can it be that the shell script failed to install it?) or it's just not correctly linked by the Python runtime. Therefore, as qarma said, verify that you have the library first, then you can set the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: You are correct. It was not finding it. Reason being it was corrupt to the point of looking encrypted. Ouch. Reinstalled from GitHub using the instructions at http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=5a088cc7506a8ca53c5820f040c1193f&p=1676317&postcount=5 and it works perfectly thus far. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer by an **explanation** how this fails:

```
sodium.crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

Here, `sodium` is most likely result of `ctypes.CDLL("sodium")`, in other words a ctypes handle to `libsodium.so`.

This line tries to tell `ctypes` module that the return type of `rypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_strprefix` function is a pointer to character, i.e. `char*`.

However `libsodium.so` that was loaded into the process doesn't have such function.

In short, there's a discrepancy between `libsodium.so` and what Python code expects to find in it.

Please check if you have more than one `libsodium` installed in the system, perhaps Python simply loads the wrong one; You could resolve that by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or explicit full path.

If you have multiple `libsodium.*`, you can check which one is loaded with `strace -eopen python somescript.py`

You can validate what symbols (incl. functions) your library has by running `nm -D /path/to/libsodium.so | grep scryptsalsa208sha256`

If you are running OSX or Win, please adjust commands accordingly...